# renaming a third party dll in .net

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I have created one tool using console application named "DocumentHashcode" in which I am   using third party DLL - `DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll`.

When I'm going to deploy it, I am using `DocumentHashcode.exe` and `DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll` for running the application.

I want to rename `DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll` to `CATBldHashCodeSupporterDll.dll`. Can anyone advise how to achieve this?

Comment: Why would you hide the fact that you use OpenXML?

Comment: Actually i made a tool, that is used by another client and they want to give their own naming conveniences, that's why. do you have any idea regarding that?

Comment: You might find an answer  here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4683913/renaming-icsharpcode-sharpziplib-dll

Comment: I have read it, but i m not finding anything helpful.

Comment: Can anyone please suggest that how can i change the name of the third party dll?

Comment: Well, the answer says, that you should not do it. But if you do so, you have to load the library manually as early as possible. Please, read the thread and understand. BTW: If you work at Google and drive a Mercedes, would you change the label on your car to 'Goocedes'? Just leave it as it is. Less problems, more fun.

Comment: that's right, but it's requirement, so i want to do that.

Comment: Well then read the article and try to follow the instructions.

Comment: which article? can you plz share it...

Comment: Please, look at my post from jan 9 7:34 above

Answer (score 5):

You need to manually load the assembly. The simplest way is to load it before the JITer tries to load the DocumentFormat.OpenXml namespace. You can manually load it like this:

```
var dllPath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "reNamed.dll");
Assembly.LoadFile(dllPath);
```

Alternatively you could listen to the [AppDomain.AssemblyResolve event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which gives you the chance to load the renamed DLL once the JITer has failed to find it.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try to re-assemble the DLL file with a new name.
For details, please check last answer in Stackoverflow: [Renaming ICsharcode-dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4683913/renaming-icsharpcode-sharpziplib-dll).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind getting a bit dirty, you can use a text editor to alter your .csproj file.   If your .dll, for example, is xr-CommInterop.dll you should find some XML like:

```
<Reference Include="xr-CommInterop, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=AMD64">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>C:\Mypath\xr-CommInterop.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

If you alter the first xr-CommInterop (in Reference Include="...) to just CommInterop and reload the project, you will find the reference now has a different name.

Comment: I was wanting to rename dll as well , hence did this but if I remove like xr and just use CommonInterlop , it for a second loads without xr and then renames automatically back to having xr.  I guess beacuse inside the hint path its still  has xr tho